# Should I use Actionscript 3.0 or Python or something else for cross-platform programming?

Tags: python, actionscript, cross-platform

I'm almost a beginner about programming. I have to do a cross-platform program for learning languages somehow like Duolingo or Rosetta Stone. I started programming with Actionscript 3.0 but I'm not sure if that language is good enough to develop that software because often I don't hear about it (could be a superstition), so I was thinking about Python since this language can do even more things that AS3 and it's very related to what I want to learn after (web and 3d related software).

The programming language should be:

- Cross-platform (Especially Windows, Mac OSX, Android and iOS - not necessarily web-oriented)
- Reliable
- Fast
- Not very complicated

Beforehand I want to give thank you to everybody who will help me.

Comment: What is the baseline for "reliable", "fast" and "not very complicated"?

Comment: - Reliable, a language program which performs without no much problems on each platform, for instance, I hear that AS3 on IOS have some limitations of file management. - Fast, I guess that a program like the one I'm doing doesn't need a low level language performance, the program have to be really stable and fluid for the final user. - Not very complicated, I don't worry too much about the complexity of a language but about the readability and subsequent development of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cross-platform

Python is very good on cross-platforms. Which is you can use [**Django**](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for web, [**Kivy**](http://kivy.org/#home) for mobile apps, [**Pygame**](http://pygame.org/news.html) for games etc etc. Python is an Open Source Code which is pretty awesome!!

- Reliable

Too broad. It depends on people, too subjective..

- Fast

Yes, Python is probably faster than Actionscript. It's in the fastest languages.

- Not very complicated

Too broad either, It depends on people, for example; for too many friends of mine Java is simpler than Python. For me, it's Python .

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer gives me more confidence about continue with python.